# AWS hosted site not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, server

I have hosted my site using amazon web services, and the site was running fine for past 30 days. after 30days we can't able to get the site. Its went down, I don't what the major problem in that.

while loading in chrome its showing "This site can’t be reached" Error : ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Please suggest me any solution regarding handling the aws regarding this problem, I'm new to aws.

Comment: Could you provide some information as to how you're hosting it? Is it an EC2 Instance running apache / nginx? Is the content hosted on S3? What have you tried to debug it? Do you have shell access to the machine? Is the security group open on the port you're trying to access it e.g. port 80 or 443?

Comment: I have hosted using ec2 instance using apache - with that linux hosting. using .pem file

Comment: If you shell into the machine and perform "curl localhost", what is the output?

Comment: this is returns like curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Comment: Have you tried "sudo service apache2 restart"?

Comment: yes tried but it says apache2: unrecognized service

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126120/discussion-between-tom-nijs-and-sridhar-g-k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restarting the Apache2 webserver:

For ubuntu

```
service apache2 restart
```

For linux

```
service httpd restart
```

If you receive a message that the restart has failed, identify which process is currently using your port:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :80
```

This will output something like

```
tcp     0     0 0.0.0.0:80   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  1607/apache2
```

The 'apache2' in this case is the name of the process using port 80.

'1607' here is the PID(process id), to shut it down execute

```
kill 1607
```

After this, try starting the service again

```
service httpd start   #linux 
service apache2 start #ubuntu
```

If this still doesn't work, try restarting the machine.

Comment: after tried **restarting the machine** it worked like charm